# Where to pass an id when testing editing functions using $this->JSON('PUT', 'url',[])

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I am writing Laravel 5.4 tests, I need to test the update method and I am not sure where to pass the `$id` for the record to be edited. When testing the store method, I just used this

```
$this->json('POST', "/example/url", [(form input here)]
```

It works fine, for the update, I do this,

```
$this->json('PUT', "/example/url", [(form input here)]
```

but for it to work I need to pass an `id` for the record I want edited. So ideally, I want to create a record using factories, then after I call the update method in the test I will assert that the fields have been edited.

```
$record = factory(Record::class)->create(['name' => 'New Name']);

$response = $this->json('PUT', "/example/url", 
             ['name' => 'Edited Name']); 
// I should pass the record->id here, I just don't know how

$this->assertDatabaseHas('records', ['name' => 'Edited Name']);
$this->assertDatabaseMissing('records', ['name' => 'New Name']);
```

Comment: I think that depends on your route definition, I'd expect it to be `"/dashboard/research/reports/".$record->id` but again, it depends how you defined the rote.

Comment: Yes that works, I use `Route::resource` I cannot believe I did not think of that.

Comment: Though you don't need the `.` just this `"/dashboard/research/reports/$record->id"`

Comment: Either way, I've ended the string at `/` and then concatenated the `$record->id` you can just put it in the string itself (it messes up with my IDE so I opt to concatenate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` should be passed as part of of the URL,

e.g; `$this->json('PUT', "/example/url/{id}", [(form input here)]`